# Matrix in C arraya

Tags: c

I have to fill a 6x5 array with numbers: 52, 62, 72 etc till array is full. But I don't have an idea how to do it. Thank you for the help.

I tried this:

```
int main() {
    int a[6][5]; 
    int start = 52;
     
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            a[i][j] = start;
            start++;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
  
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is `start+=10;`   ?

Comment: Please edit the question adding a complete example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to increment by 10 horizontally and by 1 vertically, you can modify your code this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[6][5]; 
    int start = 52, col_incr = 10, row_incr = 1;
     
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            a[i][j] = start + i * row_incr + j * col_incr;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
52 62 72 82 92 
53 63 73 83 93 
54 64 74 84 94 
55 65 75 85 95 
56 66 76 86 96 
57 67 77 87 97
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would appear to work just fine. It produces:

```
52 53 54 55 56
57 58 59 60 61
62 63 64 65 66
67 68 69 70 71
72 73 74 75 76
77 78 79 80 81
```

If you expect to see:

```
52 62 72 ...
```

You just need to increment by `10` when initializing your matrix, instead of incrementing by `1` using the `++` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything inside two nested for loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[6][5]; 
    int start = 52;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            a[i][j] = start;
            start += 10;
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: `start += 10` equals to `start = start + 10`*

This will result:

```
52 62 72 82 92 
102 112 122 132 142 
152 162 172 182 192 
202 212 222 232 242 
252 262 272 282 292 
302 312 322 332 342
```

Comment: Thanks Is there way to make function that output column 1,3 ,5

Comment: Do you mean the index of the column?

Comment: I mean I want to see numbers below column 1,3,5